# How to get visible scene rect for QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

Imagine `QGraphicsView` is set with the scene that is twice as wider as view's width. `sceneRect()` will return the whole scene rect. I'd like to get the rect representing the half of the scene with respect to scrollbars' positions.

Comment: Does the `QAbstractScrollArea::viewport()` return what you need?

Comment: @vahancho, regarding Tomas's answer, it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the viewport rectangle with the `graphicsView->viewport()->rect()` and map it to the scene space with the `graphicsView->mapToScene()`.

Comment: `viewport()->rect()` seems more appropriate to me. If we agree upon this, then you may edit your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure which rectangle you exactly need (this depends from what you want to do) but something like `graphicsView->viewport()->contentsRect()` or `graphicsView->viewport()->geometry()` should work.